# Why some accuracy measures aren't showing in caret ( F1 , Recall and precision )

Tags: r, caret

Good afternoon ,

Assume we have the following :

```
pred=c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

obs=structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("no-recurrence-events", 
"recurrence-events"), class = "factor")
```

And the following function :

```
library(plyr)
library(caret)

metrics<-function(observed1,predicted1){
  
  #predicted1=mapvalues(predicted1, from = unique(predicted1), to = unique(observed1))
  observed1=mapvalues(observed1, from = unique(observed1), to = unique(predicted1) )
  #xtab=table(observed1, predicted1)
  xtab=table(predicted1,observed1)
  #result<- confusionMatrix(as.factor(predicted1), as.factor(observed1))
  result<- confusionMatrix(as.factor(predicted1),as.factor(observed1))
  print(recall(as.factor(predicted1), as.factor(observed1)))  # i can print recall 0.9285714
  return(list(xtab,result))
  
  
}
```

After running , some measures like F1 , recall and precision aren't showing :

```
metrics(obs,pred)

[[1]]
          observed1
predicted1  1  2
         1 13  4
         2  1  2

[[2]]
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction  1  2
         1 13  4
         2  1  2
                                         
               Accuracy : 0.75           
                 95% CI : (0.509, 0.9134)
    No Information Rate : 0.7            
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.4164         
                                         
                  Kappa : 0.3056         
                                         
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.3711         
                                         
            Sensitivity : 0.9286         
            Specificity : 0.3333         
         Pos Pred Value : 0.7647         
         Neg Pred Value : 0.6667         
             Prevalence : 0.7000         
         Detection Rate : 0.6500         
   Detection Prevalence : 0.8500         
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.6310         
                                         
       'Positive' Class : 1
```

The pb is that some accuracy measures aren't showing which seems strange : F1 , Recall , precision !

I have noticed another issue , for example if we inverse the order :

```
metrics(pred,obs)

Error in confusionMatrix.default(as.factor(predicted1), as.factor(observed1)) : 
  The data must contain some levels that overlap the reference.
Calls: metrics -> confusionMatrix -> confusionMatrix.default
Execution halted
```

I hope my question is clear.

Thank you for help !

Comment: Recall would be `Sensitivity` in this output. And Precision is `Pos Pred Value`. F1, you have to compute yourself from this output. There are some tutorials on how to customize the output of caret, so you get all values. But just using these 2 is enough for most purposes.

Comment: The pb is that i have another function that uses all the 11 measures ( to plot ROC based on epochs) . It would be better if there is some way to show all measures even if some are redundant.

Comment: Also , i'm not sure if Sensitivity will be usually equall to Recall . There is something not ok here. The pb maybe in the coding of the two vectors using mapvalues of dplyr !

Comment: Yes, the values are correct. You can check with the cross table. Recall is 13/(13+1)=0.928 and Precision is 13/(13+4) = 0.765. You can extract and rename the values if you need them in another function. You can also extract one value twice and name it differently. Although, that does not really make sense.

Comment: @MartinWettstein , Thank you a lot Mr for your help . I had found a solution : confusionMatrix() has an option called mode='everything'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found a solution. `confusionMatrix()` has an option called `mode='everything'` that outputs all implemented measures :

```
pred=c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

obs=structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("no-recurrence-events", 
"recurrence-events"), class = "factor")

library(plyr)
library(caret)

metrics<-function(observed1,predicted1){
  
  #predicted1=mapvalues(predicted1, from = unique(predicted1), to = unique(observed1))
  observed1=mapvalues(observed1, from = unique(observed1), to = unique(predicted1) )
  #xtab=table(observed1, predicted1)
  xtab=table(predicted1,observed1)
  #result<- confusionMatrix(as.factor(predicted1), as.factor(observed1))
  result<- confusionMatrix(as.factor(predicted1),as.factor(observed1),mode='everything')
  return(list(xtab,result))
  
  
}

metrics(obs,pred)
```

This gives the expected outputs :

```
Loading required package: lattice
Loading required package: ggplot2
[[1]]
          observed1
predicted1  1  2
         1 13  4
         2  1  2

[[2]]
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction  1  2
         1 13  4
         2  1  2
                                         
               Accuracy : 0.75           
                 95% CI : (0.509, 0.9134)
    No Information Rate : 0.7            
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.4164         
                                         
                  Kappa : 0.3056         
                                         
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.3711         
                                         
            Sensitivity : 0.9286         
            Specificity : 0.3333         
         Pos Pred Value : 0.7647         
         Neg Pred Value : 0.6667         
              Precision : 0.7647         
                 Recall : 0.9286         
                     F1 : 0.8387         
             Prevalence : 0.7000         
         Detection Rate : 0.6500         
   Detection Prevalence : 0.8500         
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.6310         
                                         
       'Positive' Class : 1
```